# "how to erase correct listview item in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

i want to erase listview items from database, how do i link correctly each list item which its Database item?

i already have tried to delete where the _id is the list position but is not working correctly every time.

this is the  viewholder class and the getView method where i implement the listener on my adapter class

```java
  private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView nom;
        Button actualizar,borrar;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View fila=view;
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();


        if(fila==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            fila=inflater.inflate(layout,null);
            holder.imageView=fila.findViewById(R.id.imagencoche);
            holder.nom=fila.findViewById(R.id.nombreCoche);
            holder.actualizar=fila.findViewById(R.id.btnAct);
            holder.borrar=fila.findViewById(R.id.btnBorrar);

            holder.borrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MyOpenHelper db=new MyOpenHelper(context);
                    db.borrarCoche(position+1+"");

                    lista=db.selectCoches();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

            fila.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)fila.getTag();

        }
        Coche coche=lista.get(position);


        holder.nom.setText(coche.getNombre());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(coche.getFoto());

                return fila;
    }
```

the 2 method called from the SQLite helper

```java
 public  void borrarCoche(String id)
    {

        String where="_id=?";
       SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

         db.delete("coches",where,new String[]{id});
    }

 public ArrayList<Coche> selectCoches(){
        ArrayList<Coche> lista =new ArrayList<Coche>();

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c =db.rawQuery("SELECT nombre, foto, longitud, latitud,_id from coches", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                //recogemos valores
                String nom = c.getString(0);
                byte[] foto = c.getBlob(1);
                float longitud = c.getFloat(2);
                float latitud = c.getFloat(3);
                int id = c.getInt(4);
                Coche coche = new Coche(id, longitud, latitud, DbBitMapUtility.getImage(foto), nom);
                lista.add(coche);


            }while(c.moveToNext());


        }

        return lista;

    }
```

it doesnt always work correctly, sometimes it erases another entry or when there are only 2 or 1 left it donest erase nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I don't think there is need to call the items from database each time you delete an item. Rather you can delete the item from database and remove the same from list and call notifyDatasetChanged().

Further, don't call listener in getView() method rather call this inside ViewHoder class or in onBindViewHolder(). So the logic will be something like:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView nom;
    Button actualizar,borrar;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        holder.imageView=fila.findViewById(R.id.imagencoche);
        holder.nom=fila.findViewById(R.id.nombreCoche);
        holder.actualizar=fila.findViewById(R.id.btnAct);
        holder.borrar=fila.findViewById(R.id.btnBorrar);
    }
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Coche coche = cocheList.get(position); //Where ArrayList<Coche> cocheList;
    holder.nom.setText("demo text");

    holder.borrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyOpenHelper db=new MyOpenHelper(context);
                db.borrarCoche(cocheList.getId()); //Don't use position as this is not id rather this is item index value.

                cocheList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```

Hope you will get your solution.

For better understanding you can follow https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ to get a basic idea on RecyclerView in Android.

Comment: Hi @Ander Latorre, let me know if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you qwery in your Array don't have a id to select a item. I use this and you can try if you want:

Sqlite code to erase data:

```
public void borrarCoche(int id){
        this.openWriteableDB();
        String where = ConstantsBD.CAR_ID + " = ?";
        db.delete(ConstantsBD.TABLA_COCHES, where, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        this.closeDB();
    }
```

Sqlite code to Array:

```
public ArrayList selectCoches() {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.openReadableDB();
        String[] campos = new String[]{ConstantsBD.COCHE_ID, //ConstantsBD is a Class where i create the sqlite tables
                ConstantsBD.NOM, ConstantsBD.FOTO,
                ConstantsBD.LONGITUD,ConstantsBD.LATITUD};
        Cursor c = db.query(ConstantsBD.TABLA_COCHES, campos, null, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Coches coches=new Coches();
                ic.setIdCoche(c.getInt(0));//Your id always be in zero
                ic.setNombre(c.getString(1));
                ic.setFoto(c.getBlob(2));
                ic.setLongitud(c.getFloat(3));
                ic.setLatitud(c.getFloat(4));
                list.add(coches);
            }
        } finally { c.close(); }
        this.closeDB();
        return list;
    }
```

And the code to ListView in your Activity:

```
ListView listView;
ArrayList<Coches> arrayCoches;
SQLITEDB conn;

public void onResume(){
super.onResume(); 
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCoches);
arrayCoches = new ArrayList<Coches>();
conn = new SQLITEDB(getApplicationContext());
arrayCoches=conn.selectCoches();
adt =new adapterCoches(YourActivityName.this, arrayCoches);
lvCam.setAdapter(adt);
lvCam.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final  int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this)
                        .setTitle("¡Alert!")
                        .setPositiveButton("Erase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                SQLITEDB bd = new SQLITEDB(getApplicationContext());
                                bd.borrarCoche(arrayCoches.get(position).getIdCoches() );
                                onResume();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            }
                        });
                alertbox.show();
            }
}
```